# How to create function in R, which will run by parts?

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function in R, consisiting of 4 parts, which would run this parts separately. So after calling a function the first part gets executed and give me an output. The function does not close. Than I press Enter, the second part is run ang shows an output. Than after pressing Enter I get the third part executed and after the last press I have the forth part output and only than the function closes. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Try `?readline` in the console. Also, perhaps review the [minimal reproducible example guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

An arbitrary function that demonstrates the use of hrbrmstr's suggestion of `readline` is below:

```
a_b <- function(a, b){

  a_b_plus <- paste('the answer of a + b is:', a + b)
  print(a_b_plus)
  line <- readline()

  a_b_minus <- paste('the answer of a - b is:', a - b)
  print(a_b_minus)
  line <- readline()

  a_b_divide <- paste('the answer of a / b is:', a / b)
  print(a_b_divide)
  line <- readline()

}
```